# Return view not working with Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have this weird problem where my controller method works up until a point where it has to return a view.. 
I have a route
 `Route::put('/project/complete/{id}','ProjectController@complete');`

This route leads to @complete:

```
public function complete($id){
  $project = Project::find($id);
  $project->completed = 1;

  $project->save();

  return view('user.projects.project-complete', compact('project'));
}
```

Basically, what this does is just updating a field from database but I'm doing this using ajax:

```
$(".mark-complete").click(function(){
  var id = $(this).data("id");
  var url = "/project/complete/"+id;
  var token = $(this).data("token");

  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'PUT',
    data: {
        "id": id,
        "_method": 'PUT',
        "_token": token,
    },
    success: function ()
    {
      console.log("Worked.");
    }
  })
});
```

Now, this works and the field gets updated correctly. The problem is, after $project->save() I return a view as you can see.. The thing is, that view never gets returned. After I click the button, the field gets updated but I'm still on the same page, i'm not returning anything.
I checked the route and the view, everything is spelled correctly. What can be the problem here?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you never redirect to the new view, ajax is meant for staying on the same page so your results are as expected :) Maybe don't use ajax as a solution?

Comment: May we know the reason why you wanted to return the entire view in the first place?

Comment: Yes, now that I thought a little more, I don't even need to do it like this. Thanks for help, anyway! :)